# how to allow date format(DD-MM-YYYY) in the text field using javascript

Tags: javascript, date, validation, text, pattern-matching

Field is the input text not date field and it should allow only DD-MM-YYYY format.
DD(1 to 31), MM(1-12) and YYYY(0001-9999). each data character should allow only "-".

Step 1 : First two character input should allow two digit number and limit should be 1 to 28/29/30/31 based on the current year and month.
step 2 : After 1 step input should allow one digit special characters and that should allow only "-" character.
step 3 : After 2 step input should allow two digit number and limit should be 1 to 12 numbers only.
step 4 : After 3 step input should allow one digit special characters and that should allow only "-" character
step 5 : After 4th step input should allow four digits number and limit should 0001 to 9999.
step 6 : Should not allow more than 10 digits.

Using JavaScript needs to achieve the above requirement.

```html
<form id="" name="">
  <input type="text" oninput="if (!/^(?:1[0-2]|[1-9])$/.test(this.value)) { this.value = '' }" />
</form>
```

The above code i am trying to do but not able to setup the as per the requirement.

Comment: What did you try yourself? Where is your code? What part do you have issues with? Stack Overflow is _not_ the place to ask for a tutorial, nor the place to find free developers to your job for you. Especially not when it's clearly a homework assignment with the intention to _learn something_. You wouldn't learn anything if others do it for you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a homework question with no effort provided by OP and no specific problem statement other than "I don't know how to do it".

Comment: I added my code. Previous i missed the which i was trying. @icecub

Comment: That regular expression will never work. Even if it were to perfectly match your desired input, the input must still be typed out. The moment a user starts typing, your regex will fail the input and just clear it again. The assignment is far more complex than just putting a regex on it. What you should do instead is attach a function to the `oninput` event. Get the current date so you know the max values allowed. Then start testing based on current input length. Input 0? Allow 0, 1, 2 and 3 if the month allows it. Input length 1? Is the current value 0 or 1? Allow 0-9 etc..

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript without a space.